# Retrieving layer name through part of its name with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, layer-name

I'm trying to edit various layers through a plugin. Since I (and others) will be using it for multiple projects with similar structures, I need to be able to retrieve the layer's name considering it will have an extra code added to it which will change based on project.

PointLayer ABC1, PointLayerLayer DEF2, etc.
LineLayer ABC1, LineLayer DEF2, etc.

Using `QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('layer name')` I need the exact name only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you could do this:

```py
# get all layernames of project
names = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
print(names)

# filter the list of layernames
filterednames = list(filter(lambda k: 'line' in k, names))
print(filterednames)

# iterate over this filtered list and get the layer
for layername in filterednames:
    currentlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)
    # do something...
    print(layername)
```

Simply replace `'line'` with your keyword to search for. This example will iterate over all layers having the letter sequence `line` in it.

---

**Some more examples how to apply a filter more than once:**

1. basic

```py
# get all layernames of project
layernames = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]

# filter the list of layernames; apply it as often as you want
linelayers = list(filter(lambda k: 'line' in k, layernames))
pointlayers = list(filter(lambda k: 'point' in k, layernames))
abclayers = list(filter(lambda k: 'abc' in k, layernames))
deflayers = list(filter(lambda k: 'def' in k, layernames))
#...
xyzlayers = list(filter(lambda k: 'xyz' in k, layernames))

# iterate over this filtered list and get the layer
for linelayer in linelayers:
    currentlinelayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(linelayer)
    # do something...
for pointlayer in pointlayers:
    currentpointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(pointlayer)
    # do something...
#...
```

2. a little more advanced

```py
# get all layernames of project
layernames = [layer.name() for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]

# Define a list of filters
filternames = ['line','point','abc','def','xyz']

# Iterate over the filterlist
for currentfilter in filternames:
    # Apply the current filter
    filteredLayerlist = list(filter(lambda k: currentfilter in k, layernames))
    # Iterate over the current filtered layerlist
    for layer in filteredLayerlist:
        currentlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
        # do something general... or:
        if currentfilter == 'line':
            print('handle line layer')
            currentLinelayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
        elif currentfilter == 'point':
            print('handle point layer')
            currentPointlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
        elif currentfilter in ('abc','def'):
            print('handle abc and def layers')
            currentAbcDefLayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
        else:
            print('handle all other layers')
            currentOtherlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks a lot, could I use the same operation to filter multiple layers to work on ?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. This method already returns a filtered list, so you have several matching layers. In case you want different filters you can apply the filter twice or as often as you want.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking again, how do I apply the filter more than once. I need basically a list of filtered layers so I can edit the given layers. It seems that "layername" is automatically attributed to the first filtered layer and I'm not entirely sure how to get another variable with the othet layer.

Comment: Absolutely no mistake, it works perfectly and with the proper names I do get the layers I need. Thanks a lot. I do have another question but I feel this one deserves its own post at this point... I'm using this to edit layers individually without any filter:
context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):# The layer has to not be in edit mode
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f["id"] = CableID.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)

Comment: And I receive the error that the argument globalProjectLayerScopes takes should neither be a string or list but a layer variable so I'm not entirely sure what should go in there nor if editing my layers that way even works. As I'm using field calculator expressions stored in variables, Im not sure how to do these operations otherwise.

Comment: globalProjectLayerScopes() returns a type error with 'layer', 'currentLineLayer' and 'currentlayer' as they're lists or str so I can't use QgsExpressionContext and context.appendScopes to use field calculator expressions.