# How to set renderer by iterate?

Tags: pyqgis, rendering

I have read this [article](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408632/retrieving-layer-name-through-part-of-its-name-with-pyqgis) to select and filter layers for iterate, it worked in general case, however when I tried to set the symbol renderer by iterate, it didn't work,which the code is as below:

```
for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
    print(layer.name())

# Define a list of filters
filternames = ['open_']

# Iterate over the filterlist
renderer = QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer('brand')
for currentfilter in filternames:
    # Apply the current filter
    filteredLayerlist = list(filter(lambda k: currentfilter in k, layernames))
    # Iterate over the current filtered layerlist
    for layer in filteredLayerlist:
        currentlayer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer)
        print(currentlayer)
        currentlayer.setRenderer(renderer) **#crash here**
```

The result is shown as below:

```
[<QgsVectorLayer: 'open_xxxx' (ogr)>]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.3\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcod exec(code, self.locals)
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 49, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'setRenderer'
```

When I set the symbol renderer of one of the layers assigned variable name, it worked. Can I do it for all layers by iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QgsProject.mapLayersByName(...)` returns layer***s*** in a list. So even if the result is just one layer, you will get it as a single-element list.

To select the first element of the list you can use indexing and specify the zero index:

```
currentlayer = QgsProject.instance() \
               .mapLayersByName(layer)[0]
```